# How do I stop a firestore web client from reading certain documents in rules based off a documents content?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

For some reason I can run the rules simulator and it works perfectly (rejects reads on documents that have dedicated set to false) but the js app still pulls all documents if I remove the "Where" statement from:

```
    firebase.firestore().collection('live').where('dedicated', '==', false).onSnapshot
to
    firebase.firestore().collection('live').onSnapshot
```

I need to be able to list the documents, but not read the ones with dedicated = true. I know that rules are not filters, but I plan on keeping the where statement and still want to restrict the access to certain documents for security.

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /live/{document} {
      allow list: if true;
      allow read: if resource.data.dedicated == false;
    }
...
```

Comment: That's incorrect. The first way DOES NOT ensure that a web client cannot access the information. If the rules are set correctly then removing the where statement would throw an error. Same question. Anyone else know?

Answer (score 0):

Since your rules say:

```
allow list: if true;
```

This means that you allow API calls that retrieve a list of documents without any conditions.

If you only want to allow the first query, you should use:

```
allow list: if resource.data.dedicated == false;
```